# No "Thread" Module ( python 2.7 )

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

for some reason I get an error at the line containing this piece of code:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=socket)
```

this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/04 - Media/Python Projects/4 - Networking/Send_Variable_Test/Server.py", line 33, in <module>
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=socket)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
Exception AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute '_shutdown'" in <module 'threading' from 'D:\04 - Media\Python Projects\4 - Networking\Send_Variable_Test\threading.pyc'> ignored
```

its obvious from this error that apparently there is no "Thread" module in the threading library, why is this? is the fact that I'm using python 2 the reason?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a file in your path that is called `threading.py`. Rename that and also delete the `.pyc` file and it should work.

In particular at this location: `D:\04 - Media\Python Projects\4 - Networking\Send_Variable_Test\threading.pyc`

Comment: i did that, and now im not recieving the error anymore ( and that threading.py was quite a stupid thing ) but now im getting this error :

Comment: 'Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'

Comment: wait , found the problem

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan Since the original problem si fixed I would suggest marking the answer as accepted and then open a new question if anything new comes up. You should avoid asking completely new questions in comments. Esspecially since the code you have provided does not allow for much debugging